# How to create a photo grid like Facebook post in Angular?

Tags: html, css, angular, user-interface, flexbox

I want to create dynamic image display photo grid like Facebook post. Here is the sample which I am trying to achieve.

[image: Facebook Image Grid]

I want to know any solution to achieve this type of image grid. Also when there is only 1 image then it should display as a full image same like Facebook.

Is there any Angular npm package which I can use for this???

Or

Is there any simple solution which can use with flex layout??

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ngx-masonry` to achieve this.

Package link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-masonry

Demo: https://ngx-masonry-demo.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll check this and let you know.

Comment: Is there any way to show more numbers like +4 in grid